# How to distinguish asserted from inferred axioms in OWLAPI?

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

My goal is to capture separately asserted and inferred axioms by OWLAPI, in other words the distinction is between the already present axioms in the ontology and those which are not present but just inferred by the reasoner.

For example:

```
public void printHierarchy(OWLReasoner r, OWLClass clazz, int level, Set<OWLClass> visited) throws OWLException {
  //Only print satisfiable classes to skip Nothing

  if (!visited.contains(clazz) && reasoner.isSatisfiable(clazz)) {
    visited.add(clazz);
    for (int i = 0; i < level * 4; i++) {
      System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println(labelFor(clazz, r.getRootOntology()));

     // Find the children and recurse
    NodeSet<OWLClass> classes = r.getSubClasses(clazz, true);
    for (OWLClass child : classes.getFlattened()) {
      printHierarchy(r, child, level + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

the function getSubClasses returns all the subclasses of an OWL class, without making distinction if it's mentioned or not in the ontology.
I can also perform a manual check, but it could be pretty expensive.
So, my question is the following: is there a buil-in function or a work around to capture separately asserted from inferred axioms?

Comment: `OWLOntology::containsAxiom` is the way to go - this checks for asserted axioms. Clearly, You have to create that axiom first, but I guess this should be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing preexisting, as suggested in the comment you can create the axioms that the results of inferences suggest and check if they exist in the ontology. The most expensive part of the process will be the axiom creation, but that's still linear in complexity - reasoning is still likely to be the largest cost.